# Mp4 streaming not work with all files in c# webserver

Tags: c#, webserver, video-streaming, mp4

I have 2 video files with .mp4 formats and want to send them as chunked encoding
through my webserver to my clients.

Problem is when I set a breakpoint to my webserver program and send parts by delay, when I play video,
it plays in browser until read the part I've sent from my webserver and waits for webserver to send next part, until 
I push F5(contine) in debug mode and send next part to client and it plays next part.

In this file streaming works perfectly, but in second file, when I send first part or parts after that,
it won't play until I send whole file from my webserver.

Is there anything wrong from file? should I change something in file?

https://www.basiscore.com

Comment: No one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I've find my question in this link and which need to download python project from github and convert file and move metadata.

https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart